# Button causes Android app to "Unfortunately close"

Tags: java, android

Been stuck on this for about an hour now - May be an easy fix but I just cannot figure it out.

I have a button on the start screen, which once clicked will move to another activity.

This is from the xml:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_text_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/scan_button_description"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:onClick="textExtract"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_text" />
```

and this is from the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".OCRActivity">
    </activity>
```

And from the class I want to move from, I use this code to move to the other activity. (However, even by removing this code, I still get this problem - so probably not this)

```
public void textExtract(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ScannerActivity.this, OCRActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can provide the code for the activities, but I dont think this is needed

Any help would be appreciated! 
Dan

EDIT
LogCat error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFRcz.png

Comment: Post relevant logcat exception stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, im new to android dev, how do you do this?

Comment: There should be a console when you run this that spits out errors, labeled Logcat. Are you using Eclipse? Looks something like this: http://ykyuen.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/eclipse_android_debug1.png

Comment: What information is relevant, as I get lots of information coming out?

Comment: The Logcat is so nice to you: you didn't call `super.onCreate(...)` in your launching activity.

Comment: Good practice for posting a question about an Android crash: select all the red lines from the bottom of the log cat console, copy them, and paste here. Select them and click the code button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `super.onCreate(bundle);` as the first line in your `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` method.  `bundle` might be named something else, but it's whatever is passed into this method.

The same goes for other lifecycle methods in an `Activity`. For example, the first line in your `onPause` method should be a call to `super.onPause()`.

Comment: ... I would say not as the first line, but definatelly before `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OCRActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove that `android:background="@null"` line in your XML and see if that works.